# Penalize an attribute of a set of points based on their distance from a line

Tags: point, line, distance, error, distribution

We have a set of points and a line. Each point in the set has a weight attribute that is an integer. How we could penalize this weight based on the distance of the point from the line without using any sort of a threshold?

So, points that are closer to the line going to see a decrease in their weights and points that are farther from the line are not going to see that much of a difference in their weights. Is it possible to do this with some kind of a distribution?

Currently I am working on a context matching problem for shipping trajectories and their activity and in my findings, I have came across the problem of having lots of fishing activities near the coast line which is not correct and this why I am asking this question. If I manage to penalize the weight factor of points near the coastline, I can decrease the error of seeing fishing activities there.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

#### General solution (software independent)

Calculate the distance of each point to the closest point of the nearest line. Divide 1 by this value to get greater numbers for points closer to the lines. Use this number as a factor to be multiplied with the value you already have.

#### Implementation (in QGIS)

Use this expression on the point layer to create this factor and replace `line` in line 5 with the name of your line layer:

```
1/length(
    make_line(
        $geometry, 
        closest_point(
            overlay_nearest ('line', $geometry)[0],
            $geometry
        )
    )
)
```